# Thymeleaf th:value

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Using SpringMVC  + Thymeleaf, how does one bind an integer based model attribute, to an input field in a form using th:value or th:field, without having a value of '0' show in the field itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not with Thymeleaf, it is on the EL implementation of Tomcat. It doesn't respect the difference between the nullable `Integer` and primitive `int`. It is always coercing null values to 0. You can turn off this behavior using this VM argument :

`-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false`

or programatically by

`System.setProperty("org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO", "false");`

If you choose the programatic way, make sure that you invoke it during initialization of `ServletContext` (`ServletContextListener#contextInitialized`)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove th:field attribute and write id and name attributes with corresponding logical name.